# Geometry Dash - Does "Refresh Login" erase your unsaved progress?

Tags: geometry-dash

**WHY I AM ASKING THIS:**
When I tried to save, it gave an error code -5. As usual, I posted a question on Arqade ("What is the error code -5 when saving in Geometry Dash?"). Somebody gave an answer, which said to refresh login, but I didn't know whether refresh login could erase all unsaved data (I could not try it out myself because the last time I had saved was when I had 6 demons and less than 1000 stars, so if it did, then I'd basically lose all my progress)

**THE QUESTION:**
Does the Refresh Login button erase all your unsaved progress?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**
Looking it up on Google, and asking all my friends who play Geometry Dash.

Answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't erase any data at all, since you dont log out and back in, you only reenter your account details

Answer (score 1):

No. Because it is refresh, not unlink.
If you want to save your progress, I have better way for you:

1. Go in your File Explorer.
2. Go in "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\GeometryDash"(Turn on hidden files).
3. Copy all available files.
4. Paste copied files in any location you want. For example "F:\GeometryDashProgressFolder".
5. Now, "F:\GeometryDashProgressFolder" is your progress folder and if you want to load your progress, You must copy all available files in "F:\GeometryDashProgressFiles" and paste in "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\GeometryDash"

**WARNING**

It is your old progress, not new progress. If you want to load new progress, you must do all of this works again.

Comment: Yeah, I eventually found this out a few years later. Thanks for the answer!